# Deleting a path in 2D coordinate system (python)

Tags: python

Just a simple, quick question: I have to write a function delete(path,field) which will delete a path in coordinate system. Function isnt returning anything, it only remakes the field. Thus far i managed to do this:

```
def delete(path,field)
    for x,y in path:
        #this is where i got stuck, i dont know how to rename field[x][y] (coordinate) into somethin else, lets say '-'
    for column in field:
        for element in column:
            if element=='-'
                column.remove(element)
```

i think this function would work if i knew how to rename an element at specific coordinate.

Comment: "rename"? Do you want to assign a value? `field[x][y]= '-'`?

Comment: you can assign it : `field[x][y]='-'` also as you dont define the `field` as global you cant access it out side of the function scope .

Comment: Yeah, this coordinate system consists of integers, and I want to 'rename' the numbers which are on the path (path is a list of coordinates), and later delete them. I trie to assign a value but then this occurs: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple.

Comment: That means either `x` or `y` is a tuple. Please tell us exactly what you're trying to do. We can guess that `field` is a list of lists of characters, but what kind of structure does `path` have? And what's your goal?

Comment: field is a list of lists, path is a list of coordinates [(3,1),(2,3)...]. i was trying to delete the elements which were on this coordinates. but it is working now and the solution is quite simple:
http://pastebin.com/xRBWKu01